# angular 5 master detail with cdk portal

Tags: angular, angular-cdk

I building an editor UI around a canvas (konva) library and would like to achieve the following:

On the left side I would like to show a list of Icons which represent different tools (angular material mat-list) and these can be dynamically changed based in which modus the editor is. Now, if the user activates on of the tools the options of this tool should be visible somewhere else on the right side.

After a while of studying I've learned that CDK Portals+Portal-Hosts can solve this problem (see https://blog.angularindepth.com/angular-cdk-portals-b02f66dd020c)  but in his example for the tool-options he used the non ng-template part to display the icons itself. I would not like the tool-components itself to define the format to display individually their icons. Instead I'd like to pass some like '{ icon: 'some_icon', component: ToolXZYComponentClass }' to the icon-list component. But then again is there a better way to achieve this than using CDK portals at all or in this way?

Comment: Do you still need help with this? Im the author of that blog post.

Comment: Hi! sorry for the reply a year later ;)  I've got it working with portals, thanks very much for the blog post

Comment: Youre welcome!!!